# React Native: if you use arrow functions, is there ever a need to use bind(this)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, bind, arrow-functions

I know that in ES6, arrow functions have the property of not having their own `this`. Does this mean that there's no longer any scenario where you'd need to `.bind(this)` on any function in React Native? If not, can you give me a scenario where you would still need to use `.bind(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer , NO, if you use ES6 syntax to declare class methods, then `this` in them will be automatically bound to the current class instance :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  myMethod1 = () => {
    ...
  }
  myMethod2 = () => {
    ...
  }
}
```

Thats why and how javascript works with `this` keyword. So you dont need to. And to mention that it all depends on you, 
suppose you declare a method in non ES6 way, then you have to bind it.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: what if you pass the method as function to the child , you still need to bind it to parent before you call from child

Answer (score 0):

There's no need and it would also not accomplish anything. Arrow functions cannot have their `this` changed so the first argument to `.bind()` is completely ignored.

`.bind()` can still be useful for binding arguments to the function invocation though, for instance: `setTimeout(myFunction.bind(null, myVariable), 100)`. Of course, that's essentially the same thing as writing `setTimeout(() => myFunction(myVariable), 100)`

Answer (score -1):

It's still better to use them, you can even use modules that do the job for you (react autobind).

Because let's say you pass a method (`callback()` as a prob) from a parent component to a child component....

when you call that method from inside the child component with or without the arrows you get errors (not this is not defined but it the wrong one and might not find some properties such as `this.state.oncallback` in the parent component which will be the main purpose of `callback()`) since the lexical environment would be the one of the child component.

So binding it first to the parent is the right thing to do almost always :)

Comment: This is simply not true. The lexical scope of a function is wherever the function was defined. An arrow function will always have that lexical scope as its `this` and it **cannot be altered**. If you define an arrow function in the "parent" and pass it down as a property to the child, its `this` will still be the parent when invoked by the child. Running `.bind(something)` on an arrow function doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Yeah , but that simply not what i said , 
i said if you run the callback function using arrow inside the child function , that mean you pass the method as it is in probs  , then inside the child you use the arrow this here will be lexical scope of the child and not the parent